# Circle symbol for true logical statements?

Tags: logic, category-theory, propositional-calculus

I am reading the book *Introduction to Higher-Order Categorical Logic* by Lambek and Scott, and have run across this inference rule when they define what they call the "conjunction calculus":

$$A \xrightarrow{\bigcirc_{A}}T$$

What does the operator $\bigcirc_{A}$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Lambek and Scott (section 0.5)
"An object $T$ of a category $\scr A$ is
said to be a *terminal object* if for each object $A$ of
$\scr A$ there is a unique arrow $\bigcirc_A:A\to T$."

So $T$ is a terminal object in a category and $\bigcirc_A$
is the unique arrow from $A$ to $T$.

Comment: Thanks! I referred to a different text for the category theory part, so it's a little inconvenient that I missed that. Is this common notation in category theory?

Comment: @Richard No, I've never seen it before. $!_A$ is pretty common.